# jQuery - Settle parseFloat's to evert 50'ing number

Tags: jquery, parsefloat

I have some variables, which all contain numbers, and they are all parseFloat's.

In the end, all the parseFloat's are calculated into one variable, and from that variable, I need some function, that settles the specific number, into every fifty(50).. So if the specific number is 163, it needs to be settled to 150. and if its 243, it needs to be settled to 200..

This is actually working, but there is a problem tho..
The browser freezes and tells the script are LOOPing ?? I'm thinking it's because the variable betalTotal, is containing a comma number ?? like 6.5 ?

This is what I'm having so far:

```
iAlt = 0;

iAlt = maxregning - pakkerTotal - betalTotal;

//parseFloat(iAlt);
/* - THIS AINT WORKING 
if(betalTotal == 6.5){
    betalTotal.val(betalTotal.val().replace('6.5', '6,5'))
}*/

while(iAlt % 50 != 0){
    iAlt--;
}
$('#sk').text(iAlt);
```

Does anyone know a solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Divide the value by 50, round it, and multiply by 50:

```
iAlt = Math.floor(iAlt / 50) * 50;
```

(Your original method would also work if you rounded the value before the loop, but the loop is not needed at all this way.)

This will always round down, i.e. 243 to 200. If you want to round to the closest, i.e. 243 to 250, you would use `Math.round` instead.

Comment: +1 However, the examples indicate `Math.floor` instead of `Math.round`.

Comment: @jensgram: Good point. I adjusted the code to correspond with the examples, and added something about rounding also.

Answer (score 1):

iAlt % 50 will never work for you with  Float.

```
parseFloat("30.3")%2 =     0.3000000000000007
```

you can use Round , ceil , floor

Answer (score 1):

You need to compute with `Math.floor` instead of `Math.round`, here is an [test page](http://jsfiddle.net/yangchenyun/KKnSD/).

```
iAlt = Math.floor(iAlt / 50) * 50
```